# I got the error "Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server." even the URL is https

Tags: kubernetes, https

Could anybody help provide me some hints to find the root cause?
I tried to curl the URL as HTTPS, but I got the error "Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server."

Here is the output of curl

```
curl -vv --location 'https://test.wenzhi.com:443/operation/v1/test?Count=1&Az=xxx' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxx='
*   Trying 10.23.24.73:443...
* Connected to test.wenzhi.com (10.23.24.73) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Palo Alto; O=VMware, Inc.; CN=*.wenzhi.com
*  start date: Nov  3 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Dec  1 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "test.wenzhi.com" matched cert's "*.wenzhi.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert Global G2 TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/2
* h2 [:method: GET]
* h2 [:scheme: https]
* h2 [:authority: test.wenzhi.com]
* h2 [:path: /operation/v1/test?Count=1&Az=xxx]
* h2 [user-agent: curl/8.1.2]
* h2 [accept: */*]
* h2 [authorization: Basic xxxxxx=]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x138812e00)
> GET /operation/v1/test?Count=1&Az=xxx HTTP/2
> Host: test.wenzhi.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic xxxxxx==
>
< HTTP/2 400
< date: Sat, 27 Jan 2024 06:25:50 GMT
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
<
Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
* Connection #0 to host test.wenzhi.com left intact
```

Thanks a lot

I tried to curl this API https://test.wenzhi.com:443/operation/v1/test?Count=1&Az=xxx, some HTTP response is expected, never success or failure, but I got this error `Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.` which looks abnormal.

Comment: My guess is that the https server you connect to is a reverse proxy working as frontend server that accepts https connections and forwards them as http plaintext request to a backend server. But that backend server was somehow also changed to process HTPS. Only this way the error message would make sense.

Comment: Thank you Robert, yes, it's the case just as you mentioned, this error was gone after the TLS was disabled in the backend service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @Robert mentioned, TLS is enabled by ingress but I didn't disable TLS for inner service. After TLS was disabled for inner service, this error was solved.